# Show image from API in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, datatables

I want to show an image from API using laravel, I already get the image URL from response, but when I want to show it to the data table, the image URL keeps the base URL and I don't want that

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Session;

class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('pages/vehicle', [
            "title" => "Vehicle"
        ]);
    }

    public function getCategory() {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            Config::get('constants.API_URL').Config::get('constants.vehicle').'/category',
            ['headers' => 
                [
                    'Accept' => 'aplication/json',
                ]
            ]
        )->getBody()->getContents();
                    
        return json_decode($response)->data;
    }

    public function getVehicles(){
        $client = new Client();
        $user = Session::get('sessionuser');
        $response = $client->request(
            'GET',
            Config::get('constants.API_URL').Config::get('constants.vehicle'),
            ['headers' => 
                [
                    'Accept' => 'aplication/json',
                    'Authorization' => $user->token
                ]
            ]
        )->getBody()->getContents();
        return json_decode($response)->data;
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/category', [VehicleController::class, 'getCategory'])->name('vehicle.category');
Route::get('/listvehicle', [VehicleController::class, 'getVehicles']);
```

**DataTable**

```
const getVehicleData = () => { 
    tableCategory = $('#table-kendaraan').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        ajax: {
            url: `${base_url}/listvehicle`,
            dataSrc: '',
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(response) {
                toastr.error('Error get data : ' + response.statusText)
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                },
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                    return '<img src="'+JsonResultRow.qr_code+'">';
                }
            },
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'm_transport_categories.type' },

        ]
    })
}
```

the variable `$base_url` is variable that getting the base URL which is localhost.

The URL of image keeps returning the localhost URL like this

[image]

so it should be returning the base URL from API, how to do that?

Nb : I already get the response directly from JS not using controller, but the URL of image show something like this *localhosturl/baseapiurl/uploads...* and I'm running this project using PHP artisan serve

Comment: You need to double check:

1. What did store in your DB?
2. Does have any wrong base URL assigned when storing generated QR images?

Comment: the URL is fine on response or API it shows only uploads/qrcode... , but to get the image we should show the base URL API right so it can be baseurlapi/uploads/qr..
but in my case, the URL returning the base URL of localhost when I try to get the data so the image is not found because of that. I don't want the base URL of localhost is there

Comment: There are different ways to fix: Config your API URL (in your frontend code) then concat with the image path (not recommended), or concat and response via API. API is only part knows what exactly is URL from (in case you upload to third party storage).

Comment: I already did actually, but still not working

Comment: I think you should edit your post with all tried cases and explain how it's not working (may be 404 or any errors). Everyone can realize what's wrong easier.